# Animating movement of a worksheet Label

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a label move from one cell to another. I figured out the position offsets and created 3 "tweens" as animators call them. But when I run the code, the Label doesn't display until the sub has ended. If I comment out the last position the label is in the right spot. How do I make Excel update the screen to show the label before I move it again?

xo and yo are integers either -1, 0, or 1. playerLocation is a range, might as well be ActiveCell.

```
Sub moveAnimation()

Dim moveAnim As OLEObject
Set moveAnim = Worksheets(currentSheet).OLEObjects(currentSheet & "player")

moveAnim.Left = playerLocation.Left - 0.5 + yo * (playerLocation.Width / 4)
moveAnim.Top = playerLocation.Top + 0.25 + xo * (playerLocation.Width / 4)
Sleep (25)
moveAnim.Left = playerLocation.Left - 0.5 + yo * (playerLocation.Width / 2)
moveAnim.Top = playerLocation.Top + 0.25 + xo * (playerLocation.Width / 2)
Sleep (25)
moveAnim.Left = playerLocation.Left - 0.5 + yo * 3 * (playerLocation.Width / 4)
moveAnim.Top = playerLocation.Top + 0.25 + xo * 3 * (playerLocation.Width / 4)
Sleep (25)
moveAnim.Left = 0
moveAnim.Top = 0
```

Comment: I've tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `DoEvents` between each position, no change

Comment: moveAnim.Left = 0
moveAnim.Top = 0  is putting the moveANim in the same place he was before , try to delete it

Comment: After this sub the caption of the label is written to the next cell. The label is just to show the text moving between cells, so I set its position to 0,0 at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. `ActiveSheet.Calculate` will force an update so i put it between each position